# Coverity: PARSE ERROR

Tags: c, coverity, coverity-prevent

Could any one help me in figuring out if something wrong

```
#define ESS_DESC(c, t) \
    C99_INIT([ESSIF_OID_ORD(c)], {.oid = c, .str = #c ":" #t})


static const struct ESS_DESC ESS_DESC_verb[] = { ---> At all the below lines, i am getting the aprse error when executed the coverity scan.
    ESS_DESC(ESS_FULL, 16V), 
    ESS_DESC(ESS_SET_CFG, 16V),
    ESS_DESC(ESS_GET_CFG, 16V),
    ESS_DESC(ESS_GET_STATS, 16V),
    ESS_DESC(ESS_SET_CFG, 16V),
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try to force it to ignore this? It compiles and it's correct (I am assuming), it's just that the static analysis tool did not expect this kind of code and doesn't understand it, what's the big deal?, just search for an options that allows you to ignore this, there has to be one I suppose.

Comment: What's the C99_INIT macro?

Comment: #define CPP_LIST(...)              __VA_ARGS__
#define C99_INIT(_d, _v, ...)      CPP_LIST(_d = _v, ##__VA_ARGS__)

Comment: @iharob, yes it is compiling correctly.